# Профессии и род занятий

Tags: лексика

Как называется человек, который занимается фехтованием на шпагах?

Comment: Как называется ... со шпагами ?

Answer (score 2):

Псих, наверное. Чего с ними сражаться-то?
А тот, кто сражается (фехтует) шпагой - *шпажист*. Это, правда, больше спортивный термин.

Comment: Вопрос был исправлен через пару месяцев после того, как был дан этот ответ. Поэтому ответ может вызвать некоторое недоумение (я, например, не сразу догадался посмотреть историю изменений вопроса).